# Azure App Service rejected with 403 error by Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage-account

Our application server rejected by the storage account.

We generated the correct SAS token and we can reach the container in the local. (docker, intelliJ, postman)

- WebbApp and the Storage Account are in the same location (Germany West Central UTC+2).
- We have standard subsrciption/plan
- We set containers to public.
- We set IP address to firewall.
- We use azure sdk java

We try to call the Blob service.

We got an error message when the app runs on the Azure servers.

`com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance`

```
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:959d813f-601e-0057-262f-4351a4000000
Time:2021-05-07T10:53:45.0157340Z</Message></Error>"
```

[image: Update https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs2Cf.png]

**UPDATE**

We set the time zone to UTC-0.
It solved our problem. The serve run in UTC-0 time zone.

Comment: Most likely this error is coming because of the firewall rules. Because of that, your WebApp is not allowed to access your storage account.

Comment: I added a picture of my firewall settings in Storage Account.

Comment: Oh, so you don't have any firewall rules defined. Just to confirm, you can access the same storage account using the SAS URL from local? Can you share the SAS URL? Just obfuscate account name, container name and sig portion of your SAS URL.

Comment: ?sv=2020-02-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2026-05-07T18:36:25Z&st=2021-05-07T08:35:25Z&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255&spr=https,http&sig=**********

Comment: Yes, we reached the containers with SAS URL with postman and chrome but when we deployed the service into azure we get the exceptions. @GauravMantri

Comment: Your SAS token looks fine. Can you answer my other questions.

Comment: Yes, we can access the same storage from local. @GauravMantri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232079/discussion-between-geri100-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: May I know how your app service get this SAS token ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't reproduce your error. You could have a look at this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/20193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set the time zone to UTC-0. It solved our problem. The serve run in UTC-0 time zone.

Comment: how to set UTC-0?

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing you should check:

1. How you get this SAS token.
2. Did you use different containers between local and remote.

As you said, you could use it successfully on local, then you could try debug you code to get the sas uri value, and access it directly by browser.

Finally, if it not help, you could try [generate the SAS token from portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/create-sas-tokens?tabs=Containers#create-sas-tokens-for-blobs-in-the-azure-portal), and hard code the sas token to your code.

Comment: We generate the SAS token on the Azure website.