# Azure Blob Storage blob access from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) authentication

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, cloud

```
 ClientSecretCredential clientSecret = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
          .clientId("********-****-****-****-************").tenantId(
          "********-****-****-****-************")
          .clientSecret("*****~***************************~******").build();
        
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .credential(clientSecret)
                .endpoint("https://sambhutestsa.blob.core.windows.net/")
                .buildClient();
        
        
            
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("testcontainer");
        
        
        System.out.printf("Identifier for the snapshot is %s%n", blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("2824891.jpg").downloadToFile("C:\\Users\\ss255248\\2824891.jpg");
```

but getting this error can someone please help here.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:d813ea5f-d01e-004d-7b0f-656de3000000
Time:2022-05-11T08:13:50.0902556Z</Message></Error>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please consider your credentials to be exposed.  Please re-generate your credentials post-haste.   *Never* include your credentials in any posts anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve the error, please try the following:**

Make sure whether you have below **roles assigned** to your security principal:

- [Storage Blob Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)
- [Storage Blob Data Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-owner)

If not, make sure to [**assign**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) it like below:

***Go to Azure Portal ->Identify the required scope (Subscription/Resource group) -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add Role assignment***

[image]

- Check whether your application has below **API permissions**:

[image: Image2]

For more information, please **refer** this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#verify-role-assignments):

- **Otherwise**, try setting the *time zone to **UTC-0*** .
- Try adding  **`comp=list&restype=container`** to your SAS URL as a workaround.
- Make use of the snippet suggested in this **[*SO thread*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676974/unable-to-connect-to-azure-blob-storage-after-upgrading-from-v8-to-v12-java-sdk)**.

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Azure App Service rejected with 403 error by Storage Account - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434149/azure-app-service-rejected-with-403-error-by-storage-account)

[[Solved] Azure Shared Access Signature - Signature did not match - Local Coder](https://localcoder.org/azure-shared-access-signature-signature-did-not-match)